# Octave runs but graph not displayed

Tags: octave

```
num=[1];
den=[1 3 1];
G=tf(num,den);
H=1;
T=feedback(G,H);
step(T);
hold on;
Kp=23;
Ki=0;
Kd=0;
C=pid(Kp,Ki,Kd);
T=feedback(C*G,H);
step(T);
```

When run this script nothing happen in Octave but works fine in octave-online.net

[online octave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPDKY.png)

[image]
[Octave Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBXQk.png)

[image]

Comment: Did you load `control` package?

Comment: pkg load control, solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I guess there was some error message in the command windows.

Answer (score 1):

I will put a proper answer here for future users, even though OP has already solved their problem from the comments.

[octave-online.net](https://octave-online.net/) is an excellent cloud service providing an instance of octave on the cloud.

Contrary to a typical installation of octave on linux or windows, the octave-online client *autoloads* some of the more popular packages, one of which is `control`.

You can confirm this by typing `pkg list` in the octave-online console.

In your normal linux / windows installation however, this needs to be loaded explicitly before use, e.g. in the case of the control package, by doing `pkg load control`.

Your code uses the functions `feedback` and `pid`, both of which rely on the `control` package, therefore in your windows instance, your code failed, because you tried to use these functions without loading the package first.

Presumably there was also an error in your terminal informing you of this fact, that you may have missed.